# Laravel 4 - Get environment by public folder name/path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am currently working on a "multisite" feature for my current laravel 4 project (just like WordPress has it).

The simplest approach (in my opinion) would be to copy the **public** folder for each site, then it still uses the same core but you can also edit the assets for each site. The only thing that still needs to get accomplished is the different database configurations for each site.

I tried to detect the environment based on the name/path of the currently used public folder. However when i try to use `public_path()` in the **bootstrap/start.php** file it will lead to this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function make() on a non-object in
>   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php on line
>   685

How can I do that?

Comment: how are you creating the multisite? subdomain?

Comment: Currently only by accessing the different public folders, but in the future it should be done with subdomains.

Comment: No one has an idea? :(

Answer (score -1):

in laravel, it is actually more simple.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain1.example.com'], function(){
    //rotues for subdomain 1
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'subdomain2.example.com'], function(){
    //rotues for subdomain 2
});
```

i use nested controllers with namespaces for each domain.

e.g.

*Subdomain1*

```
controllers/subdomain1/HomeController
....
```

*Subdomain2*

```
controllers/subdomain2/HomeController
....
```

for *Config*

```
Config/subdomain1/database.php (e.g.)
```

and

```
Config/subdomain2/database.php (e.g.)
```

and then *setup the environment*

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => ['*.dev', gethostname()],
    'subdomain1' => ['subdomain1.example.com'],
    'subdomain2' => ['subdomin2.example.com']
));
```

....and that's it.

Comment: Using the domain to deteermine the environment is a huge security issue as it only uses the hostname, so this is not a option for me. Also i don't want to add additional routes, that is why i came up with my idea to simpy use the pathof the public folder to determine the current environment. More information: http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1qm8e3/tutorial_multisites_with_laravel_4/cdecd88

Comment: i have read that earlier. it tells the problem but doesn't show a true solution which can work pratically.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong but isn't that kind of "stupid" that you read that already but still post it as an answer without saying a thing about it? The solution is to not use domains to determine the environment.

Comment: if you go around taking every opinion of a web developer, you shouldn't be using php as a language because it is indeed an awful language comapred to python or ruby in the first hand. and moreover though people complain but still, no one has written what vulnerability it has if you use domains to detect the environment. (atleast i haven't found on the articles i read which advises against it)

Comment: In my opinion that is a very unhealthy thinking. If there are reasons to believe that a way to accomplish something is unsecure, then you should be competent enought to know in what position you are and what you are responsible for. I need it for a site with a large user base and I surely won't risk there data. If you work like that it is your thing, but I surely don't. At least you should have provided a notice to this problem when posting such an answer, but not saying anything about it is clearly the wrong way.

Comment: i am asking a simple question here. what is/are the vulnerabilities in using domain to detect environment. i don't see any so i don't put that on notice. if you know some, then share and i will add in the answer.

Comment: Take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/upgrade#upgrade-4.1 at the point "Environment Detection Updates". Taylor Otwell has removed this feature (so your answer is not working anymore anyways, if you don't have set the hostname as well), and he most likely know why. Feel free to ask him for an example.